Should I stain pressure treated wood fence posts before sinking them into the ground?
I'm sinking pressure treated 4x4s (CA-C UC4A) 36" below grade as fence posts. I'm not setting them in concrete, but will have a few inches of gravel at the bottom of the post holes to help with drainage.
I've read that staining PT wood can further extend its lifespan, but also that it has to sit for 1-2 years before it will accept stain. I don't want to wait two years to build the fence, so should I stain it now or forego the stain? Or am I asking the wrong question entirely?

No one waits 2 years with PT lumber just sitting around before starting a construction project with it.  Maybe a couple weeks to let moisture evaporate out, but certainly not 2 years.  If it were me, I'd wait a couple weeks with the 4x4s getting plenty of air outside, then stain the whole post, put 'em in the ground, and call it a day.

Fresh pressure treated wood doesn't readily accept stain/sealant into the wood. So, at best it would be a surface treatment.
I don't think it would hurt to apply extra sealant, but I don't think it would significantly help. Personally, I would not treat an uncut end, but make sure you treat any cuts you make with a sealant.

What will definitely help will be to coat/pack the end grain with epoxy. It's a bit of a pain to do, but it greatly reduces moisture flow back into the wood. I don't know if other sealants will work as well.

Some years ago, my neighbor had his 4x4 posts in buckets of Thompson's Water seal for about 2 days before he put them in the ground. ( about 6 to 8 inches of product.)  He said the posts would suck up the Waterseal and then not suck up water when in the ground. (his words)
I don't know the chemistry but his fence was still standing 12 years later when I was rebuilding mine.
